# Put a google sheets formula in a cell from Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm usign this code:

```
function doPost(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');
  
  var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, e.parameters.filename);
  var fileId = DriveApp.getFolderById(e.parameters.folderId).createFile(blob).getId();
  var lastfila= ss.getLastRow()+1; 
  const itemStock='='+'G'+lastfila+'+'+'SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO('+"'Hoja 2'!D:D;'Hoja 2'!C:C;B"+lastfila+")";
  var rowData = [];
  rowData.push(e.parameters.itemName[0]);
  rowData.push(e.parameters.itemDescription[0]);
  rowData.push(e.parameters.itemCategory[0]);
  rowData.push(e.parameters.filename[0]);
  rowData.push(fileId);
  rowData.push('https://drive.google.com/file/d/' + fileId);
  rowData.push(e.parameters.itemUnit[0]);
  rowData.push(e.parameters.itemLocation[0]);
  rowData.push(itemStock);
  sh.appendRow(rowData);
  
  

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Image: ' + e.parameters.filename + ' with ID: ' + fileId + ' successfully uploaded to Google Drive' );  
  
}
```

for some reason when adding the row created from the code, the spreadsheet does not take the formula "SUM.SI.CONJUNTO()"(SUMIFS)

[image: The problem]

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Find a way to send spreadsheet form from Apps Script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your script and your error message, how about changing `SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO` to `SUMIFS`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
const itemStock='='+'G'+lastfila+'+'+'SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO('+"'Hoja 2'!D:D;'Hoja 2'!C:C;B"+lastfila+")";
```

#### To:

```
const itemStock = '=' + 'G' + lastfila + '+' + 'SUMIFS(' + "'Hoja 2'!D:D;'Hoja 2'!C:C;B" + lastfila + ")";
```

or

```
const itemStock = `=G${lastfila}+SUMIFS('Hoja 2'!D:D;'Hoja 2'!C:C;B${lastfila})`;
```

#### Note:

- When your image of the error message, it seems `Función desconocida: 'SIMIFS'.`. I'm worried about misspellings. And also, in this case, I'm worried that you might not use `SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO`. If you are using `SIMIFS`, please modify `SUMIFS` or `SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO`, and test it again.
- In this answer, it supposes that your other part of the script works. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Función SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO (SUMIFS)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=es-419)
- [SUMIFS function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)

Comment: Sorry for the spelling errors, I am still learning English. I solved the problem by changing the spreadsheet language and using SUMIFS. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Oscar Ivan Ayala Ortiz Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.